# html - track mouse position within element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to show current position within element with a text box under cursor position. below code looks like has some offset between mouse and text box. how can I fix it to show current position within the slides box?

[image]

```js
var curTxt = document.createElement('div');
curTxt.id = "cursorText";
curTxt.innerHTML = "xx,xx";

var curTxtLen = [curTxt.offsetWidth, curTxt.offsetHeight];
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides")[0];
slides.appendChild(curTxt);

slides.onclick = onmousemove;
onmousemove = function(e) {
  var coor = getRelativeCoordinates(e, slides);
  //console.log("coor:", coor.x, coor.y);
  curTxt.style.left = coor.x + 'px';
  curTxt.style.top = coor.y + 'px';
  curTxt.innerHTML = coor.x + "," + coor.y;
}

function getRelativeCoordinates(event, referenceElement) {
  const position = {
    x: event.pageX,
    y: event.pageY
  };
  const offset = {
    left: referenceElement.offsetLeft,
    top: referenceElement.offsetTop
  };
  let reference = referenceElement.offsetParent;
  while (reference) {
    offset.left += reference.offsetLeft;
    offset.top += reference.offsetTop;
    reference = reference.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: position.x - offset.left,
    y: position.y - offset.top,
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.dot {
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.slides {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background:#ececec;
}

#cursorText {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example Mouse Tracker</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Mouse tracker</p>
  <div class="slides"></div>
  <div class="dot"><div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these changes:
the text now will be under the cursor but will not go outside your box:

```js
var curTxt = document.createElement('div');
curTxt.style.cursor = 'default';
curTxt.id = "cursorText";
curTxt.innerHTML = "xx,xx";

var curTxtLen = [curTxt.offsetWidth, curTxt.offsetHeight];
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides")[0];
slides.appendChild(curTxt);

slides.onmousemove = function(e) {
  const coor = getRelativeCoordinates(e, slides);
  curTxt.innerHTML = coor.x + "," + coor.y;
  
  const textLeft = slides.offsetLeft + coor.x - (curTxt.offsetWidth / 2)
  const textMaxLeft = slides.offsetLeft + slides.offsetWidth - curTxt.offsetWidth;
  const textTop = slides.offsetTop + coor.y + 15;
  const textMaxTop = slides.offsetTop + slides.offsetHeight - curTxt.offsetHeight;
  
  curTxt.style.left = Math.max(slides.offsetLeft, Math.min(textLeft, textMaxLeft)) + 'px';
  curTxt.style.top = Math.max(slides.offsetTop, Math.min(textTop, textMaxTop)) + 'px';
  
}

function getRelativeCoordinates(event, referenceElement) {
  const position = {
    x: event.pageX,
    y: event.pageY
  };
  const offset = {
    left: referenceElement.offsetLeft,
    top: referenceElement.offsetTop
  };
  let reference = referenceElement.offsetParent;
  while (reference) {
    offset.left += reference.offsetLeft;
    offset.top += reference.offsetTop;
    reference = reference.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: position.x - offset.left,
    y: position.y - offset.top,
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin:0;
}

.dot {
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

.slides {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background:#ececec;
}

#cursorText {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example Mouse Tracker</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Mouse tracker</p>
  <div class="slides"></div>
  <div class="dot"><div>
</body>
</html>
```